# Ajax Load more Articles button not working when posts filtered from tag or month

Tags: ajax

I have created a post filter option which allows the user to filter posts by the month or the post tags.

The issue I am having is when I click on any of the filters it filters the posts using ajax and loads the appropriate posts but when I try and click the load more posts button it reloads the page without actually accessing the ajax script.

On the home it works perfectly and for the tags if I refresh the page then use the button it works properly as well.

I am not sure what exactly might be causing this to happen. I think it might be the way I am displaying my posts.

Any help would be appreciated also if you need any code or anything please ask I shall provide you with it.

Thanks.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/G87u6w37

I have added my code here. Hope its ok 

thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wmW15knD

I have updated pastebin with the appropriate code only. Please take a look and if someone could help it would be great.. stuck on this and got no idea what is causing this to happen.

Thaks